# Allocate Swift class generated in Objc project from objc framework with its name

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am developping an application and a framework in parallel.
This application is in objc but uses a bridging header to integrated Swift classe while the framework is in objc.
In the framework I need to instantiate a Swift class from the main app knowing only its name.
To instantiate objc classes this solution works :

```
Class classToInstantiate = [[NSBundle mainBundle] classNamed:"ClassNameToInstantiate"];
return [classToInstantiate new];
```

but for swift I need to open the Project-Swift.h, find how the class has been prefixed and change the name
In Project-Swift:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC16PModuleNameClassNameToInstantiate")
@interface ClassNameToInstantiate : NSObject <ApplicationLoaderInterface>
```

I then have to write this :

```
Class classToInstantiate = [[NSBundle mainBundle] classNamed:"_TtC16PModuleNameClassNameToInstantiate"];
return [classToInstantiate new];
```

Do you know if the prefix "_TtC16" is constant or does it change all the time?

Comment: If the framework code knows the name of the Swift class and wants to instantiate it, I would assume it knows more about the class than just its name.  Maybe, design could be changed such that the framework does not have to instantiate the class in this manner?

Comment: Actually, the name is dynamically loaded from a key in the application plist. The framework contains the standard workflow of the application but can be customized if the client has specific desires. I can not think of another design that this one...